# Regex prevent matching special charakter at end. \S

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a regex string like this:

```
Hallo @info@info.com Test    #49 @info@info.at? 101.
Hallo @info@info.it!? Test#48?  @info@info.au.
Hallo @info@info.com! Test @info@info.fr
```

And I'm matching this with `[@#]\S+|[^@#]+` this regex.

Here my example:
https://regex101.com/r/KP3V9x/1

Every thing is fine so far. But I don't want to match trailing special character such as (`,.?!`) in the dark blue match, it should be match in light blue.

How do I achieve this without grouping?

Comment: [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/KP3V9x/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no grouping + trailing in light blue + main part in dark blue:

```
[@#]\S+(?<!\?|\!|\.)|[^@#]+
```

but if you want exact matches, try this:

```
[@#]\S+(?<!\?|\!|\.)
```

and if you want the 101 either, try this:

```
[@#]\S+(?<!\?|\!|\.)|\d+
```

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: no grouping + trailing in light blue + main part in dark blue.
i tried it and it gave me this result. :/